# How can I turn my cooking blog into a basic book?

Tags: print-design, book, blog

I have a blog where I've been posting recipes and pictures for the last 6 months or so. I'd like to turn these into a cookbook.

I was thinking about sticking everything in a .doc and printing it at home (it's only for a friend). Is there an easy way to do this.

In a perfect world there'd be a magic app which had a choice of layouts and dedicated space on each page for the recipe name, cooking time, serving size and directions etc. I realise though that I might need to edit some parts in Photoshop.

It would be a huge help if there were somewhere to get background images for the pages (I quite like quirky hand-drawn coloured backgrounds.

Comment: Have you tried Blurb? http://www.blurb.com/ I haven't used it myself but I've seen other people do so with good results.

Comment: Could you edit the post and talk a bit about your experience and what software options you've got. I mean do you use a basic blog and focus on the content, or do you know a bit of how the blog works? You mention Photoshop, do you have the full creative suite and any experience with it?

Answer (score 2):

One option, you could do is setup a specific CSS stylesheet for your website for print. This way you can designate a style different than your site.

It's as simple as adding new styles inside a media query of your stylesheet and add the new styles inside.

**@media print{**

*print style here*

**}**

This site has a pretty good breakdown.
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: This is one of the things I was going to suggest, just not sure if poster knows any CSS. If so this is a great option. Just make sure to use display:none pretty heavily on menus and such. Can also set it up so links get displayed as full URLs in the print version (since obviously they're not clickable).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an enormous undertaking, and this might not be *entirely* the answer you are looking for; but i hope it will help.

As @Lauren Ipsum points out, there are apps out there that will do the grunt-work for you. Here are two of them, the principle for both is automation of blog to print. You can get it "professionally" printed and bound, or just get the files. You can widen your alternatives by searching for "make book from blog".

**[Blurb](http://www.blurb.com/blog-book)**

**[blog2print](http://blog2print.sharedbook.com/blogworld/printmyblog/index.html)**